# IE9 resorts to # based url

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js

With `Backbone` `pushState` set to `true`

With IE 9 that does not have the history API, all my urls get a `#` in front example

If user enters their credentials on `www.mysite.com`

and clicks enter

They are taken to `www.mysite.com/#userdetails/` in IE 9 and other browsers that support history API they get taken to `www.mysite.com/userdetails/`

Is there a way that the URL the user would see in IE9 or IE 11 can be the same i.e. without the `#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> pushState support exists on a purely opt-in basis in Backbone. Older
>   browsers that don't support pushState will continue to use hash-based
>   URL fragments, and if a hash URL is visited by a pushState-capable
>   browser, it will be transparently upgraded to the true URL.

The only option I see is:

> If you'd like to use pushState, but have browsers that don't support it natively use full page refreshes instead, you can add {hashChange: false} to the options.

This uses full page refreshes and might not be what you want.